# How to apply hover effect to only background element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, mouseevent

I have two elements, a rect and a text, and they don't have any parent-child relationship. The text is above the rect.

I also have a function that runs on hovering the rect. The function works well when I hover the rect-only area but outFunction triggers when I hover the text which is above the rect.

I need not to run outFunction(mouseOut function) when I hover the text. It should be like there is only rect but still show the text over it.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect class='square large' x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
</svg>
<script>
    $('rect').hover(() => {
        console.log('hovering')
    }, () => {
        console.log('not hovering')
    })
</script>
```

How can I do this using jQuery or in plain JS or by tweaking some css?

Comment: Did you try `pointer-events: none`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @NoSkill worked by adding this css. Thanks.